# Store Database data to Richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox on my wpf form which i want to populate from the Database. It is giving me error that richtextbox does not contain .text property. Please help me so that i can retrieve data into RichtextBox

```
richTextBox1.text = dt.Rows[counter][6].ToString();
```

Comment: Most of the time the compiler is right: RichTextBox does have a property Text, see documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes it has but MS Visual Studio 2010 is saying that .text type of property doesnot exist.

Comment: The WPF RichTextBox does not have a Text property. You'll have to set its [Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: .Text and .text neither exist

Answer (score 0):

Actually RichTextBox does not have a Text Property. To show a string in a Richtextbox we have to do like following.

```
   richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
   richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("here you can place string")));
```